# How to get the ActionDescription UniqueId from within OnResultExecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, does anyone know a trick to access the ActionDescriptor.UniqueId from within OnResultExecuted? I need to pass information from OnActionExecuting to OnResultExecuted in a way that will work if multiple actions are executed during the one HttpRequest.

For example:

```
private Dictionary<string,Foo> _foos
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Items["foos"] as Dictionary<string,Foo>; }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Items["foos"] = value; }
}

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var foos = _foos;
    foos[context.ActionDescriptor.UniqueId] = new Foo();
    _foos = foos;
}

public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
{
    var actionUniqueId = ????
    var foo = _foos[actionUniqueId]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can custom the `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` and `ActionFilterAttribute` to implement it.

First you can create a filter that inherit the `ActionFilterAttribute` and contains `ActionDescriptor` property:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ActionDescriptor ActionDescriptor { get; set; }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionUniqueId = ActionDescriptor.UniqueId;

        //code..
    }
}
```

Then you need create a **filter provider** inherit the `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` and override the `GetFilters` method:

```
public class MyFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if (controllerContext.Controller != null)
        {
            foreach (FilterAttribute attr in GetControllerAttributes(controllerContext, actionDescriptor))
            {
                var myAttr = attr as MyActionFilterAttribute;
                if (myAttr != null) 
                {
                    myAttr.ActionDescriptor = actionDescriptor;
                }

                yield return new Filter(attr, FilterScope.Controller, order: null);
            }
            foreach (FilterAttribute attr in GetActionAttributes(controllerContext, actionDescriptor))
            {
                var myAttr = attr as MyActionFilterAttribute;
                if (myAttr != null)
                {
                    myAttr.ActionDescriptor = actionDescriptor;
                }

                yield return new Filter(attr, FilterScope.Action, order: null);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

You can see at the `GetFilters` method, We set the `ActionDescriptor` property if the filter type is `MyActionFilterAttribute`.

Finally, At `Global.asax`, you need use `MyFilterProvider` instance to replace the `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` instance in Providers collection:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //replace the FilterAttributeFilterProvider in providers collection
        for (int i = 0; i < FilterProviders.Providers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (FilterProviders.Providers[i] is FilterAttributeFilterProvider)
            {
                FilterProviders.Providers[i] = new MyFilterProvider();
                break;
            }
        }

        //other global init code...
    }
}
```